# Clear ArrayList container

Tags: java, arraylist

I would like to ask you about a way to clean container after mouse click.

```
Jbutton clearButton = new Jbutton("CLear");
ArrayList<Figure> picture = new ArrayList<>();
```

How to clean "picure" container after mouse click? I found that class ArrayList has got clear() method to remove all the elements but how to use it in a good way?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you need an actionlistener, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example of using clear :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ArrayListDemo {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

  // create an empty array list with an initial capacity
  ArrayList<Integer> arrlist = new ArrayList<Integer>(5);

  // use add() method to add elements in the list
  arrlist.add(20);
  arrlist.add(30);
  arrlist.add(10);
  arrlist.add(50);

  // let us print all the elements available in list
  for (Integer number : arrlist) {
    System.out.println("Number = " + number);
  }      

  // finding size of this list
  int retval = arrlist.size();
  System.out.println("List consists of "+ retval +" elements");

  System.out.println("Performing clear operation !!");
  arrlist.clear();
  retval = arrlist.size();
  System.out.println("Now, list consists of "+ retval +" elements");
   }
}
```

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#clear()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#clear%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

The good way: `picture.clear();`

Et voila.

For the [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html):

```
final Jbutton clearButton = new Jbutton("CLear");
final ArrayList<Figure> picture = new ArrayList<>();
clearButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        picture.clear();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `picture.clear();` since there is no other way to call it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this code is defined in a class say `MyClass`, your class can implement `ActionListener` interface.

```
public class MyClass implements ActionListener {
```

as a part of this, you will have to add a definition for the method `actionPerformed` and then add an `addActionListener` to your button `clearButton`

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == clearButton) {
        picture.clear();
    }
}
```

The above method can similarly handle different events or button clicks as well.